# Using "nesting" make a script that first prints the word from a list, and then every letter

Tags: python, list, nested

I need to make a script that will print out each item of a list and then after it each letter of that item and so on, so it needs to look like this:

```
List = ["item1" , "item2"]

item1
i
t
e
m
1

item2
i
t
e
m
2
```

I know I can print out each word with:

```
for name in list:
    print(name)
```

Just not sure how I can add a nested function to print out the letters.

This is my first asked question, if it's not up to standards I would appreciate feedback.

Comment: `for name in list:  for s in name: print(s)` Just make another cycle for each string.

Answer (score 0):

below

```
lst = ["item1" , "item2"]
for w in lst:
    print(w)
    for l in w:
        print(l)
```

output

```
item1
i
t
e
m
1
item2
i
t
e
m
2
```

Comment: definitely did, although it will not show seeing i just made my account

Answer (score 0):

Just another way:

```
for s in List:
   print(s, *s, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
item1
i
t
e
m
1
item2
i
t
e
m
2
```